# What is the highest amount of Fortify Archery I can receive on a single item?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I know that I can use larger soul stones to increase the amount, but it only goes so far. How do I get more? I do not have any DLC other than Hearthfire.

Comment: With a Grand soul, 100 levels in enchanting, and the appropriate perks you can get a 40% fortify archer per item. This can be further increased with fortify enchanting potions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there is no real answer because of the fortify restoration glitch.  This glitch allows abnormally large numbers when enchanting.  However, there are some general tips for increasing your enchanting abilities.

First, make sure to use grand soul gems or black soul gems.  Either one works for the highest level enchantments, and should be filled with a grand soul for maximum results.

You should increase your enchanting ability up to level 100.  You can do this by training with an enchanting trainer, or do it through experience.

You should also increase your alchemy to 100, since you can use fortify enchanting potions to also increase your enchanting ability.

Of course, to get better fortify enchanting potions, you should wear clothing items (Falmer Helmet/head/hands/ring/necklace) that are enchanted to give fortify alchemy bonuses.

There is a loop created here that can be repeated a few times, before increased results are diminished to zero.

1. Enchant +Alchemy clothing.
2. Wear +Alchemy clothing, create +Enchanting potions
3. Drink +Enchanting potions.
4. Repeat.

Eventually, the numbers stop going up, and you have your best +Alchemy clothes.  Use those enchanted clothing items (5 total:  Falmer Helmet+Head+Hands+Ring+Necklace) to make your best +Enchanting potions, and you are ready to create your best +Archery enchanted gear.

Comment: I believe the fortify/restoration glitch was patched. http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Thread:252227

Comment: Nope. I play on PC fully patched no mods. I started early September 2013 on my first character. More than 1000 hours and a year later, I started a new one and played it over 600 hours. Then another, also 600+ hours. It was then I loaded up the most recent save from my first character to mess about a bit with Fortify Restoration potion glitching. I already had 100 Alchemy, Enchanting and Smithing (well perked) so it didn't take long to reach some pretty game breaking numbers. When I tried to use a Fortify Smithing potion though, it said I didn't have enough skill to improve the item.